# Prove $\frac{a}{(b-c)^2}+\frac{b}{(c-a)^2}+\frac{c}{(a-b)^2}=0$ if $\frac{a}{b-c}+\frac{b}{c-a}+\frac{c}{a-b}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

> if $a,b,c$ are real numbers and $$\frac{a}{b-c}+\frac{b}{c-a}+\frac{c}{a-b}=0$$
>   Prove $$\frac{a}{(b-c)^2}+\frac{b}{(c-a)^2}+\frac{c}{(a-b)^2}=0$$

*things i have done:* using the assumption i deduced that $$\frac{a}{b-c}=-\frac{(b-c)(a-b-c)}{(c-a)(a-b)}\rightarrow\frac{a}{(b-c)^2}=\frac{(c+b-a)}{(c-a)(a-b)}$$

So some rewriting $$\frac{(c+b-a)}{(c-a)(a-b)}+\frac{b}{(c-a)^2}+\frac{c}{(a-b)^2} =\frac{(c+b-a)(c-a)(a-b)+b(a-b)^2+a(c-a)^2}{(c-a)^2(a-b)^2}$$

I tried to write numerator in expanded form but it was to large and it seemed like there was not going to be something useful after factoring. so is there any better way than my brute force ? can my solution get continued?

Comment: You have got the $a/(b-c)^2$ term in an interesting form. Try putting the other two terms in similar forms and see what happens when you add them.

Comment: @martycohen,thanks.actually it was the book hint to write one of them in this form.but as it was not useful i would try what you said.

Comment: @martycohen,thanks.your suggestion was useful.

Comment: Its a Good Question..Thanks

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma,you're welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left(\frac a{b-c}+\frac b{c-a}+\frac c{a-b}\right)\left(\frac1{b-c}+\frac1{c-a}+\frac1{a-b}\right)$$

$$=\sum\frac a{(b-c)^2}+\sum\frac b{c-a}\left(\frac1{b-c}+\frac1{a-b}\right)$$

$$=\sum\frac a{(b-c)^2}-\sum\frac b{c-a}\left(\frac{c-a}{(b-c)(a-b)}\right)$$

$$=\sum\frac a{(b-c)^2}-\frac{\sum b(c-a)}{(b-c)(a-b)(c-a)}$$

Now, $\displaystyle\frac{\sum b(c-a)}{(b-c)(a-b)(c-a)}=0$

Answer (score 4):

Put 
$$P(x)=(x-b+c)(x-c+a)(x-a+b)=x^{3}+\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma$$

We immediately have $\alpha=0$, and $\gamma\not =0$ (as $a,b,c$ are distincts).

Put $w_n=a(b-c)^n+b(c-a)^n+c(a-b)^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. We see $w_1=0$ (easy computation) and $w_{-1}=0$ (by hypothesis). Now we have $w_{n+3}+\beta w_{n+1}+\gamma w_n=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Take $n=-2$ and we get $w_{-2}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

here is an another (thanks to marty cohen suggestion on comments).

$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{(b-c)^2}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{c+b-a}{(c-a)(a-b)}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(c+b-a)(b-c)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}=0$$